# Convert geopackage into GeoJSON with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

How can I convert a GeoPackage file into GeoJSON?

```bash
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.json BGRI2021_0706.gpkg
```

returns

```
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.json BGRI2021_0706.gpkg 
ERROR 1: database disk image is malformed
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `BGRI2021_0706.gpkg' with the following drivers.
  -> `FITS'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `MBTiles'
  -> `BAG'
  -> `EEDA'
  -> `OGCAPI'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `LVBAG'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `REC'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `NAS'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `LIBKML'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `GeoJSONSeq'
  -> `ESRIJSON'
  -> `TopoJSON'
  -> `Interlis 1'
  -> `Interlis 2'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `GPKG'
  -> `SQLite'
  -> `ODBC'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `PGeo'
  -> `MSSQLSpatial'
  -> `OGR_OGDI'
  -> `PostgreSQL'
  -> `MySQL'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
  -> `DXF'
  -> `CAD'
  -> `FlatGeobuf'
  -> `Geoconcept'
  -> `GeoRSS'
  -> `GPSTrackMaker'
  -> `VFK'
  -> `PGDUMP'
  -> `OSM'
  -> `GPSBabel'
  -> `OGR_PDS'
  -> `WFS'
  -> `OAPIF'
  -> `SOSI'
  -> `Geomedia'
  -> `EDIGEO'
  -> `SVG'
  -> `CouchDB'
  -> `Cloudant'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `ARCGEN'
  -> `XLS'
  -> `ODS'
  -> `XLSX'
  -> `Elasticsearch'
  -> `Walk'
  -> `Carto'
  -> `AmigoCloud'
  -> `SXF'
  -> `Selafin'
  -> `JML'
  -> `PLSCENES'
  -> `CSW'
  -> `VDV'
  -> `GMLAS'
  -> `MVT'
  -> `NGW'
  -> `MapML'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `AVCBin'
  -> `AVCE00'
  -> `HTTP'
```

ogr2ogr supports already GeoPackage

```bash
$ ogrinfo --formats | grep GPKG
  GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
```

I am using `GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01`

Comment: The error probably means what it says and there is something wrong with your gpkg file. Some suggestions about what to do in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274202/sqlite3-database-or-disk-is-full-the-database-disk-image-is-malformed.

Comment: The GeoPKG file was OK, the problem was that QGIS was using it in parallel and apparently ogr2ogr has issues by running in parallel. But I am not fully sure

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your GPKG file may have got corrupted somehow. Maybe it wasn't closed properly after writing, or something else (could be anything really). As it's a malformed disk image, I am not sure if there is a solution here. Are you able to re-make the file or re-download it from somewhere?

Comment: The GeoPKG file was OK, the problem was that QGIS was using ogr2ogr in parallel and apparently ogr2ogr has issues by running in parallel. But I am not fully sure is this. I just know that after exiting QGIS, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full path or ogr2ogr wont find it:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.json C:\folder\BGRI2021_0706.gpkg
```

Comment: If gpkg file is not found the error is just like `Unable to open datasource foo.gpkg' with the following drivers.`. The error about malformed disk image comes from SQLite code and before that the gpkg (SQLite) data file must have been found.

Comment: If you are local to your data this shouldn't matter